# javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: java.security.cert.CertificateException: No subject alternative names present

Tags: ssl, spring-boot, ssl-certificate, spring-integration

I My application used to call WS with Https.
I use spring integration, spring boot and maven.

So i add properties:

```
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore", "/usr/lib/jvm/jre-1.7.0-openjdk.x86_64/lib/security/jssecacerts");
    System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStoreType", "JKS"); 
    System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword","changeit");
```

I have always this exception:

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: java.security.cert.CertificateException: No subject alternative names present
```

Can you please help me to solve my problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First download Installcert.java file and compile it .
After compiling run that java file by passing argument as url with port (Ws url with port) . 
Then it create jssecacert file that file you put into the /jre/lib/security folder . Hope it will work